# Is SELECT Query in MySQL return time dependent on row number

Tags: sql, mysql, time, return

With 1500 rows in MySQL, what is time difference returning first row in table or last row?

Search all text response `WHERE` query with `UserID`, `pagenumber`, `elementnumber`.

Answer (score 0):

The time difference between returning the first row and the last row in a MySQL table would depend on various factors such as the size of the table, the indexing of the table, the complexity of the query, and the resources available on the system running the query.

In general, if the table is indexed properly and the query is optimized, the difference in time between returning the first and last row should not be significant for a table with 1500 rows(Will be around 5-10ms approx).

If you have a very large data database then, there will be a time difference between which will be significant.

To search for all text responses based on a UserID, pagenumber, and elementnumber in MySQL, you can use a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE UserID = 'user_id' AND pagenumber = 'page_number' AND elementnumber = 'element_number';
```

Replace table_name, user_id, page_number, and element_number with the appropriate values for your database. This query will return all rows in the table that match the specified UserID, pagenumber, and elementnumber criteria. If the text response is stored in a separate column, you can include that column name in the SELECT statement to retrieve the text response along with the other columns.